Update where not exactly the same
If I don't want to treat an empty string and NULL as being the same value, is there a cleaner way to write the following:
-- @name and SomeTable.Name are varchar(10) NULL

update SomeTable set Name = @name
where
    Id = 5
    and (
        Name != @name
        or name is null and @name is not null
        or name is not null and @name is null)
    )

It seems dirty to use a value that I think should not be valid:
isnull(Name, '!invalid!') != isnull(@name, '!invalid!')

So if @name is NULL and column Name is not, or vice versa, or if they both have a value which is not the same, I want the update to happen.

If I don't want to treat an empty string and NULL as being the same value, is there a cleaner way - yes, to do nothing. Empty string and NULL are not the same by default.

@GSerg select * from SomeTable where Name != 'foo' won't return records whose Name is null. So that won't work. This server uses ANSI_NULLS = on, which I think is the default?

That is not the same as "empty string and null are the same", isn't it. The reason these rows don't appear is different.

You misunderstand how NULLs work, @DeveloperWebs . SomeValue (!)= NULL evaluates to UNKNOWN, which importantly isn't TRUE. That NULL != 'foo' doesn't return the row doesn't mean that it evaluated 'foo' and NULL to have the same value; SQL Server doesn't know if they do.

You don't need and shouldn't have isnull - you just need Id = 5 and (Name <> @name or (name is null and @name is not null) or (name is not null and @name is null))  - In SQL Server 2022 you can use Id = 5 and Name IS DISTINCT FROM @name

@MartinSmith right, but that's still very wordy... Is there no NULL-safe shorthand like <=> comparison from MySQL?

@MartinSmith I responded too quickly, see my last which I edited.

No. SQL Server doesn't implement any operator like <=>. 2022 has IS DISTINCT FROM. In previous versions you can use Id = 5 AND EXISTS(SELECT @name EXCEPT SELECT name) which is slightly shorter than spelling out all three conditions

@ThomA Right, which for me means the update won't happen which is not what I want :)

That doesn't make your statements about '' and NULL being equal true.

All these fail in '' vs ' '. try: WHERE id = 5 AND (select Name v for json path, include_null_values) <> (select @name v for json path, include_null_values)

@ThomA What? I'm not sure what you read. I want to update the field if it's NULL or my variable is an empty string (or vice versa). I said it because I had ISNULL in my code sample originally.

"I don't want to treat an empty string and NULL as being the same value" ergo, you appear to be saying that you think they are the same value normally; they aren't.

@ThomA because I was using ISNULL(@name, '') != ISNULL(Name, '') in the original sample. Therefore NULL and '', after ISNULL was applied, would result in the same value and my update would not happen. What you quoted was me saying I didn't want that.
