Querying for inequality on nullable columns in T-SQL
I know that both the == and =! operators outright ignore NULL values on either side, because NULL is the lack of a value and therefore cannot EQUAL another value, nor can it NOT EQUAL another value. However, when you must perform a != on columns that might have nulls, you need to code around this. In the sample code below, I have done just this, to yield the results that I want (which is the middle six rows out of the eight I've inserted). However, I can't say I'm thrilled with the complexity of this code and can't help but wonder if T-SQL provides an alternative way to get the same result. I've considered using ISNULL (or COALESCE) on either side of the !=. However, who's to say that whatever I chose as the default value with those functions isn't a valid value in the table? (For example ISNULL(val1, '') clearly wouldn't work because there are places where '' is stored as a value).
TLDR - Is there a cleaner expression to use in the WHERE clause below that would produce the same 6 results, without using ISNULL or COALESCE?
drop  table if exists #values 
create table #values
(val1       varchar(10),
 val2       varchar(10))

insert #values
values ('', ''), ('', NULL), (NULL, ''), ('A', ''), ('', 'A'), ('A', NULL), (NULL, 'A'), ('A', 'A')

select * 
from #values
where val1 != val2 OR (val1 IS NULL AND val2 IS NOT NULL) OR  (val1 IS NOT NULL AND val2 IS NULL)


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79276353/update-where-not-exactly-the-same for a few ideas in the comments

"For example ISNULL(val1, '') clearly wouldn't work because there are places where '' is stored as a value" I generally find that scenarios where both '' and NULL are present in the same column it isn't actually a desired scenario, and that likely '' or NULL should actually be the other as both values represent an "unknown" value.

where val1+val2 is null or val1<>val2   seems to produce the desired results  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/VK3S3BMZ

@ThomA NULL can mean "we dont know the value". '' can mean "We know the value and its an empty string". Regardless of whether that is a desired way of storing data, sometimes the developer querying data has no control over how data is inputted and meant to be interpreted and are at the mercy of whatever precedence already exists.

@siggemannen - THANK YOU! This comment led me to the "IS DISTINCT FROM" expression, which appears to be a new expression added to SQL 2022 (which we, luckily for me, recently upgraded to) and appears to exist specifically to address the exact challenge I outlined in my question. I trying searching & rephrasing my question to google several times to no avail, but your comment appearing 49 seconds within my post got me exactly what i needed. For others who are unfamiliar, here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

@Mike this is why I said generally, not always. Though I can't say I've ever met a scenario where NULL and '' are both permissible and mean different things. As for the developer querying it, if the quality of data is poor, then they can certainly feed that back to a developer who can control the input data. :)
